Prove that the ring of algebraic integers in an algebraic number field F is integrally closed
The question is posted here but I am still confused. I think the first answer was a wrong argument but I'm not pretty sure.
First, $\alpha\in F$, not $D$, so the elements of matrix $M$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$, not $\mathbb{Z}$, which leads the monic polynomial is in fact $\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. For the second one, we need that $I_{k}$ is a submodule of $D$ so that we can claim $I_{k}$ eventually stops. However, I can't show $\alpha b\in D$.
Is there any elementary proof of this statement? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

For the second one, I think it is better to state that $I_k$ is a $\Bbb Z$-submodule of $D[\alpha]$, which is again finitely generated over $\Bbb Z$, hence Noetherian. Then, we can just take b=1 in the argument.

Both arguments in the linked answer seem to use that $\alpha D \subseteq D$, which is true a posteriori, but I don't quite see how one finds that immediately from the monic polynomial condition (also, if that were true, we'd immediately have $\alpha=\alpha . 1 \in D$).

Slight correction to my first comment (can't edit anymore). Even if $D$ is not finitely generated over $\Bbb Z$ (e.g. $F=\Bbb C$), you can consider $E$ the subring generated by the coefficients of the polynomial for $\alpha$, which now is a finitely tenerated $\Bbb Z$-module, and $I_k$ is a submodule of $E[\alpha]$ (if you take $b=1$ again).

@FrançoisGatine But if I state $I_{k}$ is a submodule of $D[\alpha]$, I can't get a monic polynomial with coefficient in $\mathbb{Z}$, isn't it? I want to show that $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer.

$I_k$ is a sub-$\Bbb Z$-module of the $\Bbb Z$-module $D[\alpha]$ (or better, $E[\alpha]$, see above): in other words, $I_k$ is the subset generated by integer combinations of the $\alpha^i$. Now because of the noetherian property, there is an integer $n$ such that $I_n=I_{n+1}$, so $\alpha^{n+1} \in I_n$, i.e. $\alpha^{n+1}$ can be written as an integer combination of the $\alpha^i$, which is what we needed to show.

No problem now. Thanks!
